# Combinatorics Problem: Basketball Team with Players that Can Play any Position

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

**Problem.** Suppose you are to choose a basketball team of 5 players from 12 available athletes. How many ways can you choose a team composed of 2 guards, 2 forwards, and a center?

**Solution.** The way I understood the problem is that any player can be delegated to either of the three positions. There is no restriction to how many players we can only delegate to a certain position. So I assumed that the only concern I have is not over-counting the players I have already chosen for a certain role in a team of 5. Thus
$$\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{1}=23,760 \:\text{ways}$$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another approach would be to look at it as if you're are separating the 12 available players into **four** groups: The two guards, the two forwards, the one center and the seven players on the bench. This would lead to

$$\frac{12!}{(2!)(2!)(1!)(7!)} = 23760$$

Comment: Actually, that is **the same** approach.  Maybe just a slightly different view of it.  $$\dfrac{12!}{2!~2!~1!~7!}=\dfrac{12!}{2!~10!}\dfrac{10!}{2!~8!}\dfrac{8!}{1!~7!}$$  But, yes, it is a  correct approach.

Comment: Thanks! Knowing how to approach the same problem in different ways is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Graham I understand that you're saying that my approach yields the same calculation as the other(s), but I don't agree that means our approaches were the same. The OP and RobPratt used combinations, though with slightly different lines of reasoning; I looked at it as a "permutation with repetition". I suspect that any combinatorial approach to this question would end up yielding exactly the same calculation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is correct. Another approach is to first choose the five players and then assign them to positions: $$\binom{12}{5}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}=23760$$